# Scrolling text in Dialog not working

Tags: java, codenameone

I am creating a Dialog with the following code:

```
Dialog dlg = new Dialog();
dlg.setUIID("AboutDialog");
dlg.setTitle("About");
dlg.setScrollableY(true);
dlg.setScrollVisible(true);
dlg.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
SpanLabel spl = new SpanLabel(DialogText.aboutTxt[txtItem]);
dlg.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, spl);
height = screenHorizontalSize / 9;
width = screenVerticalSize / 10;
Button close = new Button("Close");
close.addActionListener((ee) -> dlg.dispose());
dlg.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, close);
dlg.show(height, height, width, width);
```

The DialogText contains several lines that need to be scrollable on low resolution devices, but the above code doesn't achieve this. What have I missed? Also tried making the SpanLabel scrollable but that didn't work.
Just moved this project from Eclipse to Netbeans (new to this). Using old GUI builder but not for this Dialog.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer - use the show methods in Dialog as in:

```
Dialog dlg = new Dialog();
dlg.setUIID("AboutDialog");
String title = "About";
String txt = DialogText.aboutTxt[txtItem];
dlg.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
dlg.setScrollableY(true);
dlg.setScrollVisible(true);
dlg.show(title, txt, Dialog.TYPE_INFO, logo_icon, "", "Close");
```

Needs a bit of tweaking but the scroll now works.
Apologies if I've wasted anyone's time.

Later: Unable to 'tweak' the above code, so in case it helps someone else, I finally got scrollable text in the Dialog using:

```
String title = DialogText.getTitleUIID(txtItem);
String txt = DialogText.dialogTxt[txtItem];

Dialog dlg = new Dialog();
dlg.setTitle(title);
dlg.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
TextArea txtArea = new TextArea(txt);
txtArea.setScrollVisible(true);
dlg.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, txtArea);
Button close = new Button("Close");
close.addActionListener((ee) -> dlg.dispose());
dlg.addComponent(BorderLayout.SOUTH, close);
dlg.showAtPosition(0, 0, 0, 0, true);
```

Comment: There are several mistakes here. `setScrollableY(true)` will be negated by `BorderLayout` which doesn't allow scrolling. You can place a content container within the center of the border layout and make it scrollable or use a Box Y container.
The first code sample creates a dialog instance and then uses a static method of Dialog to show a completely different instance. 

The last sample works because `TextArea` is scrollable on Y axis by default so it takes over the task of scrolling.